# Simple DirectX Window Error

Tags: c++, window, directx, min

So I was goofing around in DirectX as I was a beginner and I wanted a tutorial that would help. I was copy and pasted the doe from the tutorial for testing the DirectX as fast as possible but sadly there was an error regarding an undefined piece of text. I have gotten the information from here http://www.3dgep.com/introduction-to-directx-11/ 
I have stopped After the white DirectX window.
Here is the code I have entered so far for main.cpp. I doubt that the reason for this error is in another file:

```
/**
* The main application loop.
*/
int Run()
{
MSG msg = { 0 };

static DWORD previousTime = timeGetTime();
static const float targetFramerate = 30.0f;
static const float maxTimeStep = 1.0f / targetFramerate;

while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD currentTime = timeGetTime();
        float deltaTime = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000.0f;
        previousTime = currentTime;

        // Cap the delta time to the max time step (useful if your 
        // debugging and you don't want the deltaTime value to explode.
        deltaTime = std::min<float>(deltaTime, maxTimeStep);

        //            Update( deltaTime );
        //            Render();
    }
}

return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}
```

The error is on this line "deltaTime = std::min(deltaTime, maxTimeStep);"

"min" is undefined and I do not know what to do.

Comment: Did you #include <algorithm> ?

Comment: You should also ``#define NOMINMAX`` before including ``<windows.h>`` to ensure the legacy ``min`` and ``max`` macros don't mess things up.

Comment: You should take a look [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) and [Understanding Game Time Revisited](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/12/03/understanding-game-time-revisited.aspx)